# WiFi-network problem

Tags: networking, dual-boot

I am using dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.

Wifi networks are not showing in Ubuntu but it is working fine in Windows 10. It is unable to detect wifi networks on Ubuntu. When I make the hotspot then it shows only that network but it is unable to show all the available networks which can be easily shown on Windows 10.
After running [this](https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info) script, I got the report:-
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/qBfbFszrv6/plain/
When I give command dmesg, I got error as "rtlwifi: AP off, try to reconnect now" Is this a problem ?
When I give command ispci then I got [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/w89d6FhH2q/plain/) result
Please help.
Please find the attachments regarding the problem:
[Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8KgN.jpg)
[Ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hsm4f.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We notice that the signal strength is quite low, 30/70, and that you are only able to scan and see one network, yours.

```
wlo1      Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'Redmi' [AC1]>
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=30/70  Signal level=-80 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"Redmi"
                    <snip>
```

Let's force the driver to use antenna #2 to see if it helps:

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be
sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=2
```

Is there any improvement? Check:

```
sudo iwlist wlo1 scan
```

If not, please retry the above sequence but with ant_sel=1 and scan again. One of the two will produce an increase in signal strength and stability. Whichever it is, make it permanent with:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf
exit
```

Of course, use =1 or =2, whichever gives the best result.

Comment: ohh wow. after running "sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be" and 
"sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=2" , all the networks are visible now. I was facing this problem from last 2 weeks and was unable to solve. Thank you so much for the help and giving time to solve the issue. :) :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working. Have fun!

Comment: After switching off the laptop, when I switched on, again it is not showing wifi networks. After running "sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=2" in terminal, It is showing again. So, Is not there any permanent solution for this issue, I mean, can't it show networks automatically after switching on the laptop ? @chili555

Comment: Did you read and try the sequence qbove following, "...make it permanent with:"  ?

Comment: sorry, I missed that part. It is working fine now. Thank you so much for the help :)